# CollectionView reloadData in moveItemAtIndexPath resulting duplicate image sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios9

- In my app currently we need reordering images in collectionView and the first image of collectionView should reflect on imageView, So here is my implementation

  ```
  //MARK: Variable declaration

   @IBOutlet var imageViewMain: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var collectionViewImages: UICollectionView!
   var listingImages : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named:"demo_advertisement")!, UIImage(named:"camera_black")!, UIImage(named:"twitter-bird-logo")!, UIImage(named:"money-bag")!]

   //MARK: DataSource

     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

      let addPhotosCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AddPhototsCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddPhototsCollectionViewCell
      addPhotosCell.imageView.image = listingImages[indexPath.item]

      //        if listingImages.count > 0 {
      //            imageViewMain.image = listingImages[0]
      //        }

      return addPhotosCell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      // swap values if sorce and destination
      let src = listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row]
      let dest = listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row]
      listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row] = src
      listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row] = dest        

      self.collectionViewImages.performBatchUpdates({

          self.collectionViewImages.reloadData()

          }, completion: nil)

  }
  ```

What I'm trying to achieve :

- First element of collevtionView should display on imageViewMain
- Reorder the collectionView images (I'm done with this using long tap gesture on ColletionView)

**Issue :**

If I do

```
   self.collectionViewImages.reloadData()
```

in moveItemAtIndexPath while reordering images its showing me duplicate images like

[image]

I'm calling reloadData() because I need to set first element of collectionView to imageViewMain in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

**My attempt :** In case if I don't call reloadData and try to set image to imageViewMain in moveItemAtIndexPath like

```
    imageViewMain.image = listingImages[0]
```

after below lines, it will not reflect properly on imageViewMain.(But in this case reordering of images works perfectly without any duplicate image)

```
    let src = listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row]
    let dest = listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row]
    listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row] = src
    listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row] = dest
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is the proper way to implement this ?

Comment: Did you try `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` ? instead of `reloadData()`

Comment: Yes, I did also tried reloadSections but giving same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the logic which i was written in

```
moveItemAtIndexPath
```

was wrong. Instead of

```
let src = listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row]
let dest = listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row]
listingImages[destinationIndexPath.row] = src
listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row] = dest
```

It should be

```
let src = listingImages[sourceIndexPath.row]
listingImages.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
listingImages.insert(src, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
collectionViewImages.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
 addPhotosCell.imageView.image = nil
```

in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just below `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` i mean it should be second line of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Now, why it is happening ? the answer is that collection view `dequeue` the cell and `resue` it for memory efficiency and better perfomance. so sometime you are not get new image then it show previous one because image is not overridden!!

So, you have to set your cell's imagview to `nil` or you have to set some `placeholder image` that can be shown if you not got image!

Comment: Ok, let me try. I will let u know.

Comment: Nope !!! I did as u suggested, After reordering third element to second and scrolling collectionView its showing me duplicate images. Even i tried in override func prepareForReuse() {
 imageView.image = nil
  }

Comment: If you are reordering cell then you have to manage one array which contains image in reordered sequence. and you need to manage `cellForItemAtIndexpath` according to that array on every reload.

Comment: addPhotosCell.imageView.image = nil didn't worked, the logic was wrong in moveItemAtIndexPath. Anyhow thanks for answer.